# np.select pandas dataframe based on column of prefix and values

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

So I have two dataframes

> main_df, about 800 rows

| description | category |
| --- | --- |
| ABCD | ONE |
| XYZ | THREE |
| ABC |  |
| QWE |  |

> keyword_df, it is about 50 rows

| keyword | category |
| --- | --- |
| AB | FIVE |

What I'm trying to achieve =

> main_df

| description | category |
| --- | --- |
| ABCD | ONE |
| XYZ | THREE |
| ABC | FIVE |
| QWE | 0 |

> conditions = [(main_df['Description'].str.startswith('AB')) & (main_df['category').isnull()]

> values = keyword_df['category'].tolist()

> main_df['category'] = np.select(conditions, values)

I was able to create a list of strings

> ["(main_df['Description'].str.startswith('AB')) & (main_df['category').isnull()",
> "(main_df['Description'].str.startswith('CD')) & (main_df['category').isnull()", ...]

But it needs to be a list of conditions and not a list of strings for it to work.
Appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you only have 50 rows in the keyword frame, you could just iterate over those and update the main frame accordingly:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

main_df = pd.DataFrame({'description': ['ABCD', 'XYZ', 'ABC', 'QWE'],
                        'category': ['ONE', 'THREE', np.nan, np.nan]})
keyword_df = pd.DataFrame({'keyword': ['AB'],
                           'category': ['FIVE']}) 

for key in keyword_df.itertuples(index=False):
    mask = (main_df['description'].str.startswith(key[0]) 
            & main_df['category'].isnull())
    main_df.loc[mask, 'category'] = key[1] 

main_df
```

```
    description   category
0   ABCD          ONE
1   XYZ           THREE
2   ABC           FIVE
3   QWE           NaN
```